# Convert delegate to static function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I'm trying to develop a simple, one file proof of concept. The code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSString* requestString = @"https://www.example.com";
    NSURL* requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:10.0f];

    NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    return 0;
}
```

The request to `example.com` over HTTPS uses a private CA, so I need to trust that CA. To trust that CA, I need to add some code to `NSURLConnectionDelegate`'s `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`

The problem is I need the `NSURLConnection`'s delegate for the callback, and the only way I know how to do it is with another separate object.

Is it possible to flatten the delegate into a static function so I can keep all code in a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you're literally asking; the `NSURLConnction` *must* have an object as its delegate, because it's going to send specific messages, from the delegate protocol, to that object. Functions can't respond to messages. (There's no reason you can't define your delegate class in this file, however.)

There are some options for [creating on-the-spot delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438410/creating-delegates-on-the-spot-with-blocks/) which you might find useful, and in this particular case, you could use [`+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI)

Comment: Thanks again Josh. I followed the material you and vikingosegundo provided, and decided it was too involved. I broke down and added a couple more source files foe the delegate.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to have one file for one class. you can add classes in your main.m

But you will find another problem: your code will execute so fast that NSURLConnection won't have enough time to wait for anything to return. You could add a NSRunLoop [<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/run-nsrunloop-in-a-cocoa-command-line-program) [<sup>2</sup>](https://gist.github.com/syzdek/3220789).

Comment: Thanks again vikingosegundo. You were right about the `NSRunLoop`.